# forEach loop with if and else statements

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

So the title might not be the best description of my problem because I don't really know how to sum up the problem. I have a forEach loop for each event in my database and each one is classified as type = to either "trip", "ropes course", or "other". I have a section for each type of event, but I would like a way where if there are no events in the section I can not display the bannertron header and if there are no events in the whole database I can display different HTML. My code also seems very WET and I would love any suggestions on how to DRY up this page.

```
<% include partials/header %>
<div class="image-text">
  <img src="../images/trip-photo.jpg" class="bannertron">
  <div class="centered">Upcoming Trips</div>
</div>
<div class="container event">
  <% events.forEach(function(event){ %>
  <% if(event.type === "trip"){ %>
    </br>
    <h4><strong><%= event.title %></strong></h4>
    <span><%= event.startdate %> - </span>
    <span><%= event.enddate %></span>
    <h6><strong>Location: </strong><%= event.location %></h6>
    <p><%= event.description %></p>
    <% if(currentUser && (currentUser.admin === true)){ %>
      <a href="/calendar/<%= event._id %>/edit" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
      <form action="/calendar/<%= event._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
      </form>
    <% } %>
    <hr class="event-hr">
    <% } %>
  <% }); %>
</div>
<div class="image-text">
  <img src="../images/climbing-photo.jpg" class="bannertron">
  <div class="centered">Upcoming Climbing Days</div>
</div>
<div class="container event">
  <% events.forEach(function(event){ %>
  <% if(event.type === "ropescourse"){ %>
    </br>
    <h4><strong><%= event.title %></strong></h4>
    <span><%= event.startdate %> - </span>
    <span><%= event.enddate %></span>
    <h6><strong>Location: </strong><%= event.location %></h6>
    <p><%= event.description %></p>
    <% if(currentUser && (currentUser.admin === true)){ %>
      <a href="/calendar/<%= event._id %>/edit" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
      <form action="/calendar/<%= event._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
      </form>
    <% } %>
    <hr class="event-hr">
    <% } %>
  <% }); %>
</div>
<div class="image-text">
  <img src="../images/other-photo.jpg" class="bannertron">
  <div class="centered">Other Events</div>
</div>
<div class="container event">
  <% events.forEach(function(event){ %>
  <% if(event.type === "other"){ %>
    <h4><strong><%= event.title %></strong></h4>
    <span><%= event.startdate %> - </span>
    <span><%= event.enddate %></span>
    <h6><strong>Location: </strong><%= event.location %></h6>
    <p><%= event.description %></p>
    <% if(currentUser && (currentUser.admin === true)){ %>
      <a href="/calendar/<%= event._id %>/edit" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
      <form action="/calendar/<%= event._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
      </form>
    <% } %>
    <hr class="event-hr">
    </br>
    <% } %>
  <% }); %>
</div>
<% include partials/footer %>
```

Ideally, I would be able to loop through the events, check which type it is, put it in its respective area, and if there are none of a type, display some text like "no events scheduled" and if there are no events in total, display something else.

Comment: You can get information about the events. So, at the top, you could have `if no events...` and then the HTML for that case...and it also looks like the only thing that is different each time is the image . You could Dry up the code by moving the guts of your html in the for loop into another .ejs file. Then, create a filter each time and for each type of event `<% include partials/eventdetails %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this was me, I would split the events up into 3 different arrays in the node file, instead of sorting it all out inside of an ejs file. The Array.prototype.filter command would be useful for this. The nice thing about it is it returns a new array, with only items that return true for the function you pass in. It does not alter the original array, just passes a new one in. You can do something like

```
var trips = events.filter(function(event){
   return event.type == "trip";
});
//do similar for "rope course", and for "other" you could do something like
return event.type != "trip" && event.type != "rope course"
// for the return statement.
```

You can do a

```
if(events.length == 0){
// show different html file
} else {
// show the html file with events, passing in the arrays
}
```

Make sure you pass all the arrays into the ejs file. For each array, you can do a similar

```
if(trips.length != 0){
// show banner and stuff
}
```

And do it for all three.
Hope this helps!